# Simplifying the Kullback-Leibler divergence for a sum of distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, kullback-leibler, approximation, exponential-family, variational-bayes

I want to find an approximation of a mixture of probability distributions that minimises the Kullback-Leibler divergence (KLD).
I need to verify my result, as it seems suspect.

We have a joint distribution
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) = \prod_{k=1}^{K} \big( \pi_{k} \, p_{k} (\mathbf{x}) \big)^{z_{k}},
\end{align}
where $p_{k}(\mathbf{x})$ is a probability density function, and $\pi_{k}$ is a weight that must satisfy $0 < \pi_{k} \leq 1$ together with $\sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_{k} = 1$.
Here $\mathbf{z} = \begin{bmatrix}
z_{1} & z_{2} & \cdots & z_{K}
\end{bmatrix}^{T}$ is a $1$-of-$K$ binary variable, where $z_{k} \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{K} z_{k} = 1$.
That is to say, one element of $\mathbf{z}$ must equal one, while the rest must equal zero.
The marginal of $\mathbf{x}$ is the $K$-component mixture
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{\mathbf{z}} p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_{k} \, p_{k}(\mathbf{x}).
\end{align}
We now introduce a similarly defined joint distribution
\begin{align}
q(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) =  \prod_{k=1}^{K} \big( \pi_{k} \, q(\mathbf{x}) \big)^{z_{k}},
\end{align}
where $q(\mathbf{x})$ is a probability density function.
I want to find the optimal $q(\mathbf{x})$ that minimises the KLD
\begin{align}
D_{\text{KL}} (q (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) \, || \, p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) ) &= \sum_{\mathbf{z}} \int q(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) \log \Big( \frac{ q(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) }{ p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z})  } \Big) d \mathbf{x}.
\end{align}
I believe the KLD can be simplified as follows:
\begin{align}
D_{\text{KL}} (q (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) \, || \, p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) ) &= \sum_{\mathbf{z}} \int \Bigg( \prod_{i=1}^{K} \big( \pi_{i} \, q(\mathbf{x}) \big)^{z_{i}}  \Bigg) \Bigg(  \sum_{i=1}^{K} z_{i} \log \Big( \frac{ q(\mathbf{x}) }{ p_{i} (\mathbf{x}) }  \Big) \Bigg) d \mathbf{x} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{K} \int \pi_{k} \, q(\mathbf{x}) \log \Big( \frac{ q(\mathbf{x}) }{ p_{k} (\mathbf{x}) }  \Big) d \mathbf{x} \\
&= \int q (\mathbf{x}) \, \log \Big(  \frac{q(\mathbf{x})}{ f (\mathbf{x})  } \Big) d \mathbf{x} - \log(Z),
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{Z}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{K} \big( p_{k} (\mathbf{x}) \big)^{\pi_{k}} 
\end{align}
and $Z$ is a normalising constant.
The KLD is minimised when $q(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x})$.
Is my simplification of the KLD correct?

Comment: This is phrased so generally that it’s hard to think through — is there a more concrete version, tied to some application?

Comment: Approximating a Gaussian mixture (GM) using a single Gaussian distribution. This is useful in belief update message passing algorithms in the field of probabilistic graphical models, as it avoids the propagation of GMs. Expectation propagation is an example of this approximate message passing. In EP, we minimise $D_{KL} ( p(x) || q(x) )$; however, this can lead to numerical instabilities. I wanted to see if I could minimise the reverse KLD, but working with the explicit mixture seemed intractable, so I opted to use the joint.

Comment: I think you’d be more likely to get a good answer by asking something closer to what you’re really interested in. The current focus on the joint distribution might or might not be helpful, and meanwhile confuses me where “approximating a mixture of Gaussians by a single Gaussian” seems clear.